# The CSS settings for the font are not adopted

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

If I include the Source Sans Pro font in my CSS sheet and check the font in the browser with the Inspector, then Source Sans Pro is shown. But it is Times New Roman.

[image: font-family is Source Sans Pro]

When I go to the Fonts tab in the Inspector, it also says Times New Roman. It also won't `font-weight: 300;` accepted. Why is the Source Sans Pro font not being adopted?

[image: font-family is Times New Roman]

```css
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-BlackItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-ExtraLight.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-ExtraLightItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-LightItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf") format("ttf");
} 
@font-face { 
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro"; 
  src: url("../fonts/source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBoldItalic.ttf") format("ttf");
} 

:root {
  font-size: 62.5%
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Titel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <main>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
    </main>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to include your different fonts of the same family with different @font-face

Comment: And you did not specify a `font-weight` for your paragraph, so the default `normal` will apply, and that is equivalent to `400`. Your `@font-face` rule however says `font-weight: 300`

Comment: The error is still the same even after doing include the different fonts of the same family with different @font-face. See edited code from first post